# filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) not working in if condition

Tags: php, email, email-validation

I am validating email using- filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL).
I want to echo a statement saying 'invalid email' if the above function returns false. However irrespective of if-statement 'invalid email' echoed on the screen from the beginning of time when page loads. Help.

This is my code:

```
<?php $emailErr = ""; ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<ul class="form-style-1">
<li>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input placeholder="Email*" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
</li>
<?php 
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){
$emailErr = "Invalid email.";
echo $emailErr;}?>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you create `$email` ?

Comment: this problem happened to me but i relised that i put `filter_vars()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it seems that you don't check if `$email` is set before validating the email. as an empty string or `null` is not a valid email, the test fails and the message `invalid email` is displayed

You should use this :

```
if(!empty($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email.";
    echo $emailErr;
}
```

Comment: before the user submits his email, `$email` contains the value `null` so the function `filter_var` will try to validate `null` as an email. this will fail as null is not valid and that is why the error message will be shown. you have to check if the var `$email` contains something before trying to validate the content. that is done with the function `empty`